# Make lingering hover repeat action in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#test').hover(
 function () {
  $(this).append('Blah');
 }
);
```

How can I make the jQuery repeatedly append `Blah` in `#test` based on how long you are hovering over `#test`?

For instance, how can I append `Blah` once every second you are hovering over `#test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `setInterval` like this :

```
var myInterval = false;
$('#test').hover(
   function(){
      $that = $(this); 
      // need to save $(this) as 'this' will be different within setInterval
      myInterval = setInterval(function(){
         $that.append('Blah');
      }, 100); // repeat every 100 ms
   },function() {
      clearInterval(myInterval);  // clear the interval on hoverOut
   }
);
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/zqkDz/1/)

Comment: Is there any advantage in using `false` for a non-running interval (there probably is, I just don't know it)?

Comment: Nah. Using `var myInterval;` would've been just the same.

Comment: @m90 nope ... just like to initialise the var

Comment: Could you demonstrate this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @UserIsCorrupt already have ... see the example link at the bottom of the answer - please note the `$that = $(this)` line and comment below to explain it

Answer (score 2):

```
(function() {
   var intv;
   $('#test').hover(
     function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        intv = setInterval(function() {
          $this.append('Blah');
        }, 1000);
     },
     function() {
       clearInterval(intv);
     }
  );
}());
```

I've enclosed all the code inside a anonymous scoped function so to not pollute global scope, and I cached  a reference to `$(this)` to avoid a new evaluation every second, inside the timeout

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)** to do so:

```
var appending; //var to store the interval

$('#test').hover(function(){ //on mouseenter
   var $this = $(this); //store the context, i.e. the element triggering the hover
   appending = setInterval(function(){ //the following function gets executed every second until the interval is cleared
      $this.append('<p>Blah</p>'); //append content to context
   },1000); //1000 meaning the repetition time in ms
},function(){ //on mouseleave
   clearInterval(appending); //clear the interval on mouseleave
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval()

```
$('#test').hover(
 function () {
setInterval(function() {
  $(this).append('Blah');
},1000)
 }
);
```

Comment: and `$(this)` will not work in there .... try it on a http://jsfiddle.net/ and you will see (or wont as the case may be !!)